# Drop down parameter is not getting updated

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a drop down with three options(report 1, report 2, report 3), and on selecting one of them nothing gets update as I try to view my report.

```
SELECT
  ProjInfo.ProjName,
  ServerInfo.ServName,
  ServerInfo.Type,
  ServerInfo.Version
FROM ProjInfo, ServerInfo
WHERE Version IN(@ServerReport)
GROUP BY ServerInfo.Version, ServerInfo.Type, ProjInfo.ProjName
```

I think my `Where` statement is wrong, but not sure how so.

Comment: This is an issue with SSRS.. it only refreshes the parameters on initial run.. subsequently changing the parent parameter does not refresh child parameters.. it's a pain.. but if you make them multiselect.. they seem to work.. it works for me..

Comment: The main issue is that it not displaying anything at all even selecting first time. I already had set it up as multiple values.

Comment: Does it work if you have only one selection for the @serverReport parameter?

Comment: No it doesn't, because in my parameter I have report1 set to a value of 10 for example. So when the user selects report1 it goes and finds all the versions that start with 10.

Comment: umm... where Version in (@serverReport) will not give you anything like 1* if the selection is 1.. IN is not for wildcard selection..  it mean something like 

Where Version IN (1,2,3) for example.. Does your SQL run ok on it's own if you substitute @ServerReport with actual values?

Comment: This maybe incorrect but there is no join in your from clause........